# Bounding Box (how to make it and how to use it for auto holes)?

Tags: workflow

***Hello***, its been a long time since i was here... I kinda don't remember how to ask a question here (properly)

So I will just ask, I would like to create a bounding box that would be used as a auto cutting of an object in **Blender 2.8**, a permanent cut (like with a knife) but done automatically, unless you think I should do it differently. That could be good too but some tutorial would be nice.

My issue is I have 5 doors on each side in a hallway and I want to keep it as simple as its possible, at least for now. Later I will want to make walls that will be imported to a game engine but for now I just want to make something simple and then go from there

Comment: Hi, Towik, could you describe in more detail what the result would be if you achieved your goal?

Comment: Well, the thing is if I could just make a plane and grab a side to make it longer and use some kind bounding box for instant cutting where the doors would be, it would be faster. at this moment I have to make a plane, after rotating it so it would be vertical, after that I have to grab one edge move it, then I have to make a loop, at the height of the door, then I select the edge above the door and E, then I end up with the wall above the door, then I have to E the wall to the next door and after that I have to extrude the edge to the floor... and so on